# netbeans 6.1 - cannot gets a variable type hovering the mouse on it

Tags: c, netbeans

On the netbeans that I am using, I cannot do a basic thing such hovering the mouse over a variable and getting its type as shown in the below picture.
How can I obtain this behaviour?

On my system there is windows XP, Netbeans 6.1 and my application is a Vega7000 Application

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using such an old version? It may well be a bug or simply a missing feature.

So answer is, upgrade!

https://netbeans.org/downloads/

---

If you need the old version for release builds, you can perhaps still do the actual development and debugging using a newer and shinier version.

Also, if you are not using one yet, use source control! I prefer *git*, but this is very subjective, other DVCS are good too. And note that so called distributed VCS works extremely well locally inside one source tree directory, it does not have to be distributed to many places. When working with old fragile complex code you are afraid of breaking, *very* frequent local commits, and diffing to known-good versions when problems arise are life savers. If you care about publishing work in progress, at least *git* (presumably all DVCS) allow squashing multiple commits into one before pushing to non-personal repo or branch.

Comment: Because I have to add new feature on an Old buggy application that was developed by someone else and I am scared that updating it something will not work anymore! I will try that way ...

Comment: @eeadev Added a bit of text to answer based on your comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is a Castles' plugin on this netbeans 6.1 and I would upgrade it only if I know 100% that this is caused by an older version of this plugin. it sounds strange to me that an IDE of 5 years ago does not have such a common feature (mouse hovering) implemented. I would rather accept a response telling me about a bug's trace.